# Instantiate view controller from storyboard in second project in workspace

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xcode-workspace

I created a workspace with 2 projects in it, let's call them A and B, with bundle identifiers `com.domain.a` and `com.domain.b` respectively. Each of the projects has a story board called `Main.storyboard` in them. I have a button in the storyboard of project A and I want to instantiate a view controller from the storyboard in project B with the following code:

```
@IBAction func clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let bundle = NSBundle(identifier: "com.domain.b")
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("aVC")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

I also have set the storyboard ID for the view controller in project B:

[image: Storyboard ID]

But when I build and run the project I get this exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7f8578cd34d0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'aVC''
```

## NOTE:

I used breakpoints and found out that the variable `bundle` in my code in `nil`. **why?!**

Comment: are you sure you are calling the right story board and the name is correct?

Comment: @MohsenShakiba yes, the string literals are correct, as I said the problems seems to be the bundle which is set to `nil`, I don't know what I'm doing wrong about that.

Comment: Hade you declared the class `public`?

Comment: Are you sure that accessing something from a different project is even possible?

Comment: @xoudini What class?! I want to work with storyboards

Comment: @YashTamakuwala yes :)

Comment: Since you're trying to access a class from another module you'll have to take access control into account.

Comment: Can you change storyboard name and try again. I understand bundle identifier is specified correctly so logically it should work but still change storyboard name to supposedly `MainB.storyboard` and see if its working.

Comment: @MeetShah Tried that too, It did not work.

Comment: Any one help me on this? I am facing this same issue. Any one found solution for this?